# centering input in form mailchimp

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I'm having a problem with centering my input[type="submit"].
I'm using bootstrap on my website also.
I tried many ways but nothing seems to work. Can someone please help me with this?

```
 .centerButton{
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.btnsubmit{
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 60px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #60C3AD;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: You can use the bootstrap class for center `.text-center` - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

Comment: Can you use it to align the whole div in the center of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with the below link you have a button at center just as you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/wmDL8/26/

```
<div id='toolbar'>
<div class='text-center'>
    <div class="btn">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default"/>

    </div>
</div>
```